# Проблемы с подключение к серверу на Android API 20 и ниже

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Приложение обращается к php файлу на сервере, для проверки данных пользователя. На Android API 20 и выше, все работает. Если API ниже 20, то возникает следующие ошибки:

```
07-17 10:12:43.870 1424-1439/com.example.verum.optron001 W/System.err: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
07-17 10:12:43.870 1424-1439/com.example.verum.optron001 W/System.err:     at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:381)
07-17 10:12:43.870 1424-1439/com.example.verum.optron001 W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connectTls(RealConnection.java:302)
07-17 10:12:43.870 1424-1439/com.example.verum.optron001 W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.establishProtocol(RealConnection.java:270)
07-17 10:12:43.870 1424-1439/com.example.verum.optron001 W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.java:162)
07-17 10:12:43.874 1424-1439/com.example.verum.optron001 W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:257)
07-17 10:12:43.874 1424-1439/com.example.verum.optron001 W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:135)
07-17 10:12:43.874 1424-1439/com.example.verum.optron001 W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:114)
07-17 10:12:43.874 1424-1439/com.example.verum.optron001 W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.java:42)
07-17 10:12:43.874 1424-1439/com.example.verum.optron001 W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
07-17 10:12:43.874 1424-1439/com.example.verum.optron001 W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
07-17 10:12:43.874 1424-1439/com.example.verum.optron001 W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.java:93)
07-17 10:12:43.874 1424-1439/com.example.verum.optron001 W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
07-17 10:12:43.874 1424-1439/com.example.verum.optron001 W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
07-17 10:12:43.874 1424-1439/com.example.verum.optron001 W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.java:93)
07-17 10:12:43.874 1424-1439/com.example.verum.optron001 W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
07-17 10:12:43.874 1424-1439/com.example.verum.optron001 W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:126)
07-17 10:12:43.874 1424-1439/com.example.verum.optron001 W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
07-17 10:12:43.874 1424-1439/com.example.verum.optron001 W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
07-17 10:12:43.874 1424-1439/com.example.verum.optron001 W/System.err:     at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:200)
07-17 10:12:43.874 1424-1439/com.example.verum.optron001 W/System.err:     at okhttp3.RealCall$AsyncCall.execute(RealCall.java:147)
07-17 10:12:43.874 1424-1439/com.example.verum.optron001 W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.NamedRunnable.run(NamedRunnable.java:32)
07-17 10:12:43.874 1424-1439/com.example.verum.optron001 W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
07-17 10:12:43.874 1424-1439/com.example.verum.optron001 W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
07-17 10:12:43.874 1424-1439/com.example.verum.optron001 W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
07-17 10:12:43.874 1424-1439/com.example.verum.optron001 W/System.err: Caused by: java.security.cert.CertificateException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
07-17 10:12:43.874 1424-1439/com.example.verum.optron001 W/System.err:     at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(TrustManagerImpl.java:276)
07-17 10:12:43.874 1424-1439/com.example.verum.optron001 W/System.err:     at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(TrustManagerImpl.java:197)
07-17 10:12:43.874 1424-1439/com.example.verum.optron001 W/System.err:     at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.OpenSSLSocketImpl.verifyCertificateChain(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:584)
07-17 10:12:43.874 1424-1439/com.example.verum.optron001 W/System.err:     at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.NativeCrypto.SSL_do_handshake(Native Method)
07-17 10:12:43.874 1424-1439/com.example.verum.optron001 W/System.err:     at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:378)
07-17 10:12:43.874 1424-1439/com.example.verum.optron001 W/System.err:  ... 23 more
07-17 10:12:43.874 1424-1439/com.example.verum.optron001 W/System.err: Caused by: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
07-17 10:12:43.874 1424-1439/com.example.verum.optron001 W/System.err:  ... 28 more
```

Возможно это связано с тем, что [TLS 1.1+ не включен по умолчанию](https://developer.android.com/reference/javax/net/ssl/SSLSocket) до API 20. В чем заключается моя ошибка, и как это можно исправить?

Comment: Хм... похоже проблема в сертификате, проверка которого выполняется только в API 20 и ниже...

Comment: Код который подключается к серверу: https://github.com/Nulllix/debug/blob/master/Code.txt